# How do i catch error of authentication while logging in and signup using firebase and flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am pretty new to flutter and this is my first project in which i am using backend like firebase.
So i pre build an ui and started to integrate firebase in it it was successfully done and it is working as accepted but when i am trying to print out the errors while logging in signup i am failing to do that, i am able to catch the errors in my console but i wait to update my users with that error text.
when ever i am trying to log in though i am providing a wrong password it is taking me to the home page which i dont want

**This is my Log In page with a pre build ui and with working setup of log in**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notepad/Authentigation%20Screens/signUp.dart';
import 'package:notepad/animation/bouncypagetrans.dart';
import 'package:notepad/animation/fadeanimation.dart';
import 'package:notepad/auth/authMethod.dart';
import 'package:notepad/screens/homepage.dart';
import 'package:notepad/widgets/VxTextsHeaders.dart';
import 'package:notepad/widgets/customRaisedButton.dart';
import 'package:notepad/widgets/loading.dart';
import 'package:notepad/widgets/textformField.dart';
import 'ForgotPassword.dart';

class LogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogInState createState() => _LogInState();
}

class _LogInState extends State<LogIn> {
  String error;
  AuthMethods authMethods = new AuthMethods();
  bool isLoading = false;
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController emailTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  logMein()  {
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      try {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });

        authMethods
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailTextEditingController.text,
                passwordTextEditingController.text)
            .then((val) {
          // print("${val.uId}");
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            BouncyPageRout(
              widget: HomePage(),
            ),
          );
        });
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          error = e.message;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      body: isLoading
          ? Loading()
          : SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 100.0, 30.0, 20.0),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          FadeAnimation(
                            1.0,
                            headerTitle("Hello,"),
                          ),
                          FadeAnimation(
                            2.0,
                            headerSubTitle("Log in to continue"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 65),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Form(
                              key: formKey,
                              child: Column(children: [
                                SizedBox(height: 20),
                                
                                FadeAnimation(
                                  3.0,
                                  buildTextField(
                                      validator: (val) {
                                        return val.isEmpty ||
                                                RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                                                    .hasMatch(val)
                                            ? null
                                            : "Please provide a valid Email";
                                      },
                                      labelText: "Email",
                                      controller: emailTextEditingController),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 20),
                                FadeAnimation(
                                  3.5,
                                  buildTextField(
                                      validator: (val) {
                                        return val.isEmpty || val.length < 6
                                            ? "Please Provide a Strong Password,/n Provide somthing greater than 6  "
                                            : null;
                                      },
                                      labelText: "Password",
                                      obscureText: true,
                                      controller:
                                          passwordTextEditingController),
                                ),
                              ])),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: FadeAnimation(
                              4.0,
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    BouncyPageRout(
                                      widget: ForgotPassword(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  'Forgot Password?',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.deepOrange,
                                      fontSize: 14),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 40),
                          FadeAnimation(
                            4.5,
                            raisedButton(
                              context: context,
                              onPressed: () {
                                logMein();
                              },
                              color: Colors.deepOrange,
                              title: "Log In",
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20.0,
                          ),
                          FadeAnimation(
                            5.0,
                            raisedButton(
                                context: context,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    BouncyPageRout(
                                      widget: SignUp(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                title: "SignUp"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }


}
```

**AuthMethods page with contains all the codes of firebase**

```
import 'package:notepad/auth/user.dart';

class AuthMethods {
  String error;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(userId: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future signUpwithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future resetPass(String email) async {
    try {
      return await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

so basically i want to notify my users a valid error message and untill they solve that they should not navigate to a perticular screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `snackbar` widget and call them in your throw function! Follow this link to learn more about snackbars
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars